# Which version of widgetset Vaadin 7 application is using?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

Is there a way to determine the version of the widgetset downloaded?
I have an application that is a Vaadin application, I should want to find a command to launch in the console of chrome that tells me, which version of the widgetset is in use?

Comment: 1) what do you mean by the "version of the widgetset"? Do you mean the Vaadin version used to build the widgetset or something else?

Comment: 2) why do you need to know the version  of the widgetset? What is the original problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: 1. yes, the vaadin version used to build the widgetset, but on the browser; I know the version on the server;

Comment: 2. I need to know the version because I'm going to change from one version to other; And lookin at the networks tab sometimes I see that the downloaded is one version and in sometimes is another;

Comment: How will you know the Vaadin version used to build the widgetset is not the one you expect, and what are you going to do once you know?

Comment: I'm working in a portal and there are so many portlet, and it happens to see in some page/portlet the one that is on the server and in other page/portlet the old one; And if I'm able to determine the right widgeteset downloaded, it will be valuable for me!!

Comment: You might want to edit the Question and add all of this information there.